# What is the less expensive way to Traverse Through ExecutionResult in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am very new in [Neo4j data base](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/index.html) .

I am taking above site as a reference and try to create nodes of data storing and retrieving the nodes and there respective properties.

For Retrieving the nodes i am using following method :

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query,map);
Iterator<Object> columnAs = result.columnAs("n");

while(columnAs.hasNext())
      {
        Node n = (Node)columnAs.next();
           for (String key : n.getPropertyKeys()) {
                Sysout(key);
                Sysout(n.getProperty(key));
            }
      }
```

For Executing above while loop it takes lots of time it takes almost 10 - 12 sec to traverse 28k nodes.

**I am not sure whether I am following proper method or is there any other alternative for this.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What interface are you using? REST? Can you try to test a Cypher query that simply counts these results so we can eliminate transport and Sysout overhead? Something like `start n = node(*) return count(n)` or whatever is giving you the 28K results.

Comment: Not using REST. After removing sysout it takes 5-6. Even if I remove inner for loop then it takes around 1-2 sec. Why it takes too much time to get the property from nodes. ?

Comment: Have you tried to run the test multiple times without restarting? Got that store and the test somewhere to check?

Comment: what does your query look like?